# How the drag and drop system works with Xlib in C++?

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, glfw, xlib, imgui

I am developing an application in C++ with the gui frameworks ImGUI.

My ImGUI backend is GLFW.

I need to create a drag end drop system (between my app and others) for my app but for what I've been reading, GLFW only support drop events from external applications but not drag output event (or I missed it ?).

I'm on Linux (ubuntu 20.4) and so I decided to implement this with Xlib directly.

But, I have no clue where to start.

1. - Where is the official documentation for XLib ? (edit : [found it](https://x.org/docs/X11/xlib.pdf))
2. - I've seen a tutorial which explained how to create windows etc. but no information on the drag n drop system
3. - My openGL window is created with GLFW, so is it even possible to create a drag output system from it ?

Something important here: my question is not about how to detect a drag event from the mouse.
**It's really about how to put data in the drag n drop system of Xlib**.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You are looking for information about the [xdnd protocol](https://johnlindal.wixsite.com/xdnd), which is off-topic for SO. Searching for "xlib xdnd" yields a nice demo application you can study. You could also try studying the drag and drop implementations of GDK (GTK) and Qt.

Comment: freedesktop.org (probably) hosts the [authoritative spec](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/XDND/)